# How to stop Windows masking content of user home?

Tags: windows-explorer

I have a bunch of files and folders stored in c:\users\username. If I open explorer and go to the shortcut to my name, or go up a level from Downloads or Documents, or even type c:\users\username in the location bar, I get a few "library" folders (contacts, desktop, favorites, etc.) but none of my actual files. To see the real flee content, I have to manually browse to c:\ and go from there. How can I disable the stupid hide-the-user's-content-from-the-user behavior?

Comment: What happens if you put %userprofile% into Windows Explorer's address bar? (including the percent signs), is it the same? Can you provide a screen-shot?

Comment: Same behavior. If I start>run that path, I get the useless fake library view. If I browse to a physical directory in c:, then put that path in the location bar, then it goes to the real folder.

Comment: Strange, not happening for me. What happens if you go to the "fake" view and turn on view hidden items?